# Laravel Pgination not working when putting link after foreach

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am facing some issue with pagination link. When I am adding this code:

```
{{ $wachat->links() }}
```

After foreach I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links() (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kc/kyo-webservice/resources/views/wechat/show.blade.php)
```

In my controller I am using this code:

```
public function wechatshows($d1, $id, $name, Request $request)
{
    $users = Keyuser::where('imception_id', '=', $d1)->first();
    $user = UserKey::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    if ($name == "all") {
        $wachat = Wechat::where('key', '=', $d1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    } else {
        $wachat = Wechat::where('key', '=', $d1)->where('groupName', '=', $name)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    }

    $wechatcontact = Wechat::select('groupName')->groupBy('groupName')->get();
    return view('wechat.show', ['wachat' => $wachat, 'user' => $user, 'product' => $d1, 'users' => $users, 'keyUser' => $d1, 'wechatcontact' => $wechatcontact]);
}
```

I am using this code in my views:

```
            <tbody id="chatListBody" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                    @foreach ($wachat as $wachat)
                    <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" class="wechatname" data-id="{{ $wachat->id }}">
                        <td>{{ $wachat->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $wachat->wxid }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $wachat->username }}</td>
                        @if ($wachat->type === 'image')
                        <td><a class="example-image-link" href="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}" data-lightbox="{{$wachat->imgPath}}"
                                data-title="{{$wachat->imgPath}}"><img class="imgwhatsapp" data-lightbox="roadtrip" src="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}"></a></td>
                        @elseif ($wachat->type === 'video')
                        <td><a href="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}">{{$wachat->imgPath}}</a></td>
                        @elseif ($wachat->type === 'audio')
                        <td> <a href="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}">{{$wachat->imgPath}}</a> </td>
                        @elseif ($wachat->type === 'text')
                        <td>{{$wachat->message}}</td>
                        @else
                        <td>no data</td>
                        @endif
                        <td>{{ $wachat->created_at }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                {{ $wachat->links() }}
            </div>
        </table>
```

When I am putting {{ $wachat->links() }} above foreach it is working I don't know why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, `$wachat` is getting override inside `@foreach($wachat as $wachat)`. so, it can not find `links()` method.

you should use `@foreach($wachat as $singleWachat)` or as per your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through your collection, Your collection become object. After the loop when you do {{ $wachat->links() }}. Your Code try to paginate a object and error shown.
Avoid this kind of problem try to use your collection variable name plural and your object name singular.

```
public function wechatshows($d1, $id, $name, Request $request)
{
    $users = Keyuser::where('imception_id', '=', $d1)->first();
    $user = UserKey::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    if ($name == "all") {
        $wachats = Wechat::where('key', '=', $d1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    } else {
        $wachats = Wechat::where('key', '=', $d1)->where('groupName', '=', $name)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    }

    $wechatcontact = Wechat::select('groupName')->groupBy('groupName')->get();
    return view('wechat.show', ['wachats' => $wachats, 'user' => $user, 'product' => $d1, 'users' => $users, 'keyUser' => $d1, 'wechatcontact' => $wechatcontact]);
}
```

and

```
 <tbody id="chatListBody" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                    @foreach ($wachats as $wachat)
                    <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" class="wechatname" data-id="{{ $wachat->id }}">
                        <td>{{ $wachat->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $wachat->wxid }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $wachat->username }}</td>
                        @if ($wachat->type === 'image')
                        <td><a class="example-image-link" href="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}" data-lightbox="{{$wachat->imgPath}}"
                                data-title="{{$wachat->imgPath}}"><img class="imgwhatsapp" data-lightbox="roadtrip" src="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}"></a></td>
                        @elseif ($wachat->type === 'video')
                        <td><a href="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}">{{$wachat->imgPath}}</a></td>
                        @elseif ($wachat->type === 'audio')
                        <td> <a href="{{ url('/images/'.$wachat->imgPath.'') }}">{{$wachat->imgPath}}</a> </td>
                        @elseif ($wachat->type === 'text')
                        <td>{{$wachat->message}}</td>
                        @else
                        <td>no data</td>
                        @endif
                        <td>{{ $wachat->created_at }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                {{ $wachats->links() }}
            </div>
        </table>
```